# How to add floating window to my silver light dynamically?

Tags: ajax, silverlight, dynamic, childwindow

I have list of Activity in my Database which shows in treeview nodes in Ajax, after clicking each nodes it calles different webpart and add to my Ajax screen App.

Want to know is it possible to do the same thing with silverlight floating window?

which I want to show task on treeview, and by clicking node invoking childwindow or floatingwindow in silverlight.

In Ajax we have webpart URL which by passing the url we can add it to main page.

Anybody can help plz.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same sort of thing can be done in Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

If you want to open a child window when clicking a node, this how you need to show up your child window,

```
ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow();
cw.Show();
```

add this to your node click event, in order to capture the childwindow properties you can add a closing event and do whatever you want.